# Julia crashes when loading images in loop

Tags: image, file-io, crash, julia, png

I have a folder of PNG files, and I am trying to load them in a loop using the Julia language. There are 136 files, and Julia (in the Atom/Juno environment) crashes 9 images in. Currently, my script looks like this:

```
using Images
using FileIO

filePaths = glob(filetype, cmpnFldr)
fileNames = [split(x,"\\")[end] for x in filePaths]
numFiles = length(fileNames)

# Show data type,size
img = load(filePaths[1])
@info("",size(img),typeof(img)
```

which yields

```
┌ Info: 
│   size(img) = (768, 1024)
└   typeof(img) = Array{RGB{Normed{UInt8,8}},2}
```

In a loop,

```
for i in 1:numFiles
    @info(i)
    img = load(filePaths[i])
    img = Gray.(img)
end
```

resulting in

```
[ Info: 1
[ Info: 2
[ Info: 3
[ Info: 4
[ Info: 5
[ Info: 6
[ Info: 7
[ Info: 8

Julia has exited.
Press Enter to start a new session.
```

I tried processing the files in a loop using [other forum posts](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-load-a-collection-of-image-files-with-images-jl-or-imageview-jl/30829/4), but nothing's worked out. It feels like there should be a more efficient method to do this. Maybe I'm using the wrong package? I've tried specifying where the `load` method is being called from, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: What is the value of `numFiles`? What happens when you run your loop `for i in 8:9`?

Comment: Are you using ImageIO.jl or ImageMagick.jl to load the files? Try ImageIO first (`Pkg.add("ImageIO")`).

Comment: @tholy ImageIO works great, thank you! I'm still curious, though, why other Image-based packages (ex. Images, FileIO) would cause a crash.

Comment: Once you install ImageIO, it should be used by the entire Images ecosystem. If you didn't have it before, it uses ImageMagick if you have that installed. But ImageMagick has been problematic almost from the beginning for us, so I highly recommend always installing ImageIO and then ImageMagick only if you need support for formats not available through ImageIO.